# Javascript not working in dot net nuke module?

Tags: dotnetnuke

i am working on dotnetnuke modules. I am using following javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    alert($('#sl-slider').slitslider());
});

</script>
```

for sliding images . here all the js files are loading . but javscript not at all working . i am using 06.01.02 (98) version of dotnetnuke . should i change the version or what ?
Please help me for this problem ? thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

As a safety measure with DNN I tend to always use jQuery versus the $ example
jQuery(function(){ alert(jQuery('#sl-slider').slitslider();});

I assume you are using alert just to see if Javascript is running?
See if switching the $ to jQuery helps at all... sometimes depending on what other modules you have installed their can be collisions.

I don't see it pasted above but I assume you also have a starting

Comment: ya Sir. I am using alert to check javascript is running or what .Javascript is not running here .I am trying to solve this problem from last two days . but i could not make javascript running .Please , Help me . How can i find out the solution for this problem ?

Comment: If you are running Chrome and you right click anywhere in the web app and do 'inspect element' it should open up the debug console. In the lower right do you see a red X with a number next to it? Click on it and it should show you any javascript errors you may have. It's possible you have a javascript errors?

Comment: I dnt think its javascript error .. i debugged javscript by using firebug .. javascript is working fine but its not returning anything to alert($('#sl-slider').slitslider()); .

Comment: Does <script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function(){alert('jquery working');});</script> do anything for you?

Comment: There are ywo errors in the javascript . when i checked google chrome i found it .. the errors are .1) Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on' jquery.slitslider.js:144
2)Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: this is the line no . 144 which is showing error .. please tell me how can resolve this ..

Comment: Without seeing this live anywhere or having any screenshots or code I can't really provide any additional feedback.  The path to your js file could be wrong, the initializer of your module might not be running right ...